# Content Porter 2009 import without Publication Metadata

Tags: content-porter-2009

I use Tridion Content Porter 2009 - Build 3.0.0.1371. 
When exporting content (components) from environment A, it will automatically import the publication properties/metadata on environment B. Such as:
- Publication path
- Publication URL
- Images path
- Images URL

I mark all possible checkboxes to exclude items during the export and import.
I wonder... is there a way to skip or avoid importing publication properties/metadata when importing to environment B?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After selecting your items to import, right-click on each Publication that is now checked and select "Selected children only." This will stop Content Porter from importing the Publication itself (along with its metadata):

[image: Content Porter - Selected Children Only]